# cannot inilialize input with some value

Tags: jquery, html

I have a piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#account').val('1234567890');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="account" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

And I cannot set input value, it's empty. But I have one very bad solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //todo: very bad solution
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#account').val('1234567890');
            }, 100);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="account" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

I set timeout to change input value and it works. How can I do that in a better way?

Comment: Is this *all* your code? The DOM-ready callback you have in the first example should work. Aside from that, a better practice is to put all your scripts right before `</body>`.

Comment: Did you tried moving the script tags below body tag?

Comment: did you check the console for errors?

Comment: @j08691 there was a problem with my browser. Now works! Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

You should use $(document).ready(). Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="account" type="text" />
</body>
</html>
```

And this will be your JS

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#account').val('1234567890');
    });
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoWLVM)